# Could I get all the linearly independent cycles of length 4 if I iteratively cut one of the edges in the 4-membered cycles detected?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I would like to get all the linearly independent 4-membered cycle in a graph. Suppose that there are $n$ linearly independent 4-cycles in the graph. If I cut one of the edges in a 4-cycle found, is it true that the remaining graph contains $n-1$ linearly independent cycles of length 4? Does anybody know a proof/counterexample? How could I generate all the linearly independent cycles of length 4 in a bipartite graph?

Comment: What about two 4-cycles that share a single edge (6 vertices)?  The cycle space has dimension $2$ and the two 4-cycles form a basis.  But if you cut the shared edge the graph only has one 6-cycle, not a 4-cycle as you conjecture.

Comment: Oh, it is true. Is it any idea how to get all the linearly independent 4-cycle in a very large undirected bipartite graph?

Comment: The bipartitenees condition sounds interesting.  You should add it to your question as it gives a lot more possible structure to the $4$-cycles.